# Why doesn't button draw correctly when using Auto Layout?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, drawing, autolayout

I created a new Cocoa Application which is using auto-layout. On the window, I added a NSView which nearly fills the window. Inside of this NSView, I placed a button in the upper left corner. When I run the application and resize the window to its smallest width and then resize the window to its largest width, the button will not draw correctly. If I turn off auto-layout and try the same procedure, the button will draw correctly.

When resizing the window, I only grab & drag the right hand side of the window.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but I am not certain what that might be.

I have a sample test project here:  [autolayout test](http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/autolayout01.zip)

[image: After resizing narrow and then back to wide quickly]
[image: AFter resizing partially narrow and then back to wide]

Comment: You say it doesn't draw correctly. Would you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Added. Do you not see the same problem? I have trivially reproduced this now on several machines.

Comment: What are the constraints on the view?

Comment: I literally just dragged two views into IB. The constraints are whatever IB decided should be the default constraints without any modifications by me. I would suggest downloading the project and taking a look at the xib or just creating your own test project and recreate the problem. However, you can grab some screen shots at http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/autolayout01-01.png, http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/autolayout01-02.png, & http://ericgorr.net/cocoadev/autolayout01-03.png

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshots. Would you try setting a minimum size for the window of about 250x250? I think that should fix the problem you're seeing. Basically, the constraints in the second screenshot don't make sense when the window gets really small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce this.  It appears to happen only to NSButtons (also NSTextFields, and probably many other NSView subclasses) that are aligned to the inner NSView's left edge; objects aligned to the inner NSView's right edge or horizontal center redraw appropriately.

I can fix it by creating an NSView subclass and replacing the inner NSView with an instance of the subclass.  but I believe I shouldn't have to.  Eric, I'd suggest filing a bug report as an Apple Developer: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: Seems to be a drawing issue. If I click on the "invisible" button (or where it supposed to be), it becomes visible. You guys see that ?

Comment: Yup, I see the same thing.  I've never encountered it myself, because I try to prevent objects from being clipped or obscured in the first place.  But the issue probably shouldn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that subclassing NSView and using that subclass as the parent view of the button resolves the issue. It appears the subclass does require at least an empty -drawRect: method. I have filed a bug report: rdar://12888108 which can be referenced should anyone else desire to do the same.